# Try to drop columns in R,returning logical vector

Tags: r, dataframe, dynamic-columns

I have a dataframe where i need to drop certain columns by column names. column names are generated like this

```
drops  <- sprintf("days.7.%d",1:7)
```

my dataframe is `df`, I want to drop generated columns and this is what i have tried.

```
dfnew <- df[,(!names(df) %in% drops)]
```

It is returnining again a logical vector instead of dataframe.

I tried these methods as well,but everytime it returns the same logical vector

```
  dropnames<- names(df) %in% drops
  dfnew <- df[!dropnames]

  dfnew <- df[ , -which(names(df) %in% drops)]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably have `data.table`. See this example

```
df <- mtcars[, 1:9]
names(df)[1:7] <- drops
df[,(!names(df) %in% drops)] #works

#                    vs am
#Mazda RX4            0  1
#Mazda RX4 Wag        0  1
#Datsun 710           1  1
#Hornet 4 Drive       1  0
#Hornet Sportabout    0  0
#...
```

Now convert it to `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)
```

and try the same thing

```
df[,(!names(df) %in% drops)] #you get
#[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE
```

To subset `data.table` by name you can do

```
df[, setdiff(names(df), drops), with = FALSE]

#    vs am
# 1:  0  1
# 2:  0  1
# 3:  1  1
# 4:  1  0
# 5:  0  0
# 6:  1  0
#...
```

Comment: This is correct..but i read my data as a dataframe `dat.train <- fread(file=train.set, stringsAsFactor=F, data.table=F)` and when i print the class of the dataset it shows as `"data.table" "data.frame"`. is it possible to convert dataframe to data.table during manipulate the dataframe

Comment: @RajithThennakoon yes, your data is being read as `data.table`. I am not sure if I understand your question exactly. To convert from `data.frame` to `data.table` you can use `setDT(df)` or `as.data.table` and `as.data.frame` from data.table to data.frame.